# Setting properties on a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, properties

I need to set a property on a `UIView` from a `UIViewController`. Sounds simple enough (`MorePlanDetails` is a `UIView`),

```
MorePlanDetails *moreDetails = [[MorePlanDetails alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-80)];
moreDetails.plan = self.plan;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:moreDetails];
```

The property on MorePlanDetails is defined the usual way:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *plan;
```

and synthesized:

```
@synthesize plan = _plan;
```

This should do it, doesn't it? But for some reason `moreDetails.plan` stays `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is self.plan perhaps null?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, use self.plan. But actually you don't even need to add "@synthesize" anymore, as long as you have the @property the compiler will generate the getters and setters for you.

Add:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *plan;
```

Reference in code:

```
self.plan = whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting moredetails.plan as null then the the value returned by self.plan is null You can get more clarity if you debug the code using debugger and more over no need of using synthesize property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simple enough. I was initializing my widgets -- which depend on the plan object -- in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, but setting the plan object only in the next line. So obviously it was null for the widgets.

The solution is to simply initialize the widgets in a separate method, and call it only once the plan is set on moreDetails.

The workin code:

```
MorePlanDetails *moreDetails = [[MorePlanDetails alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-80)];
moreDetails.plan = self.plan;
[moreDetails initWidgets];
```